# How to fetch data from a website using LibreOffice's Calc?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm searching for a way to fetch some data from a website using LibreOffice's Calc.

I was using Google Sheets with the IMPORTXML function before, but because it's very unreliable I want to use Calc instead.

My functions there looked like this:

> =IMPORTXML(E2; "//h3[@class='product-name']")
>
> =IMPORTXML(E2; "//span[@class='price']")

As you can already guess, the URL was in E2 (f.i. http://www.killis.at/gin/monkey-47-gin-distiller-s-cut-2016-0-5-lt.html).

In Calc I've tried `=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(E2);"//h3[@class='product-name']")` only to get `#VALUE!` as a result.

My LibreOffice's version is 6.0.4.2 with German locale. I use English function names with ";" as a separator.

So what would be the equivalent for this function in Calc and how would the appropriate command for the product name and price look like?

Comment: Perhaps `FILTERXML` is not able to parse that page correctly because it is not plain XML.  The following formula works: `=FILTERXML(WEBSERVICE(E2);"//temperature[@unit='kelvin']/@value")` for URI http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=London&type=like&mode=xml&appid=b6907d289e10d714a6e88b30761fae22

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that while [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) claims to be able parsing tag soup HTML, which is not true in all cases, the [FILTERXML](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/WEBSERVICE#FILTERXML) needs a valid XML stream per definition. And tag soup HTML is not a valid XML stream. To be honest, HTML mostly is the opposite of a valid XML stream.

So the only way would be using third party tag soup parsers or taking the HTML tag soup as string and using string operations to find the needed parts of the string.

The second approach could look like this:

```
Public Function GETFROMHTML(sURL as String, sStartTag as String) as String

   on error goto onErrorExit
   oSimpleFileAccess = createUNOService ("com.sun.star.ucb.SimpleFileAccess")
   oInpDataStream = createUNOService ("com.sun.star.io.TextInputStream")
   oInpDataStream.setInputStream(oSimpleFileAccess.openFileRead(sUrl))
   dim delimiters() as long
   sContent = oInpDataStream.readString(delimiters(), false)

   lStartPos = instr(1, sContent, sStartTag )
   if lStartPos = 0 then
     GETFROMHTML = "tag " & sStartTag & " not found"
     exit function
   end if   
   lEndPos = instr(lStartPos, sContent, "</")
   lStartPos = lStartPos + 1 + len(sStartTag)
   sText = trim(replace(replace(mid(sContent, lStartPos, lEndPos-lStartPos), chr(10), ""), chr(13), ""))
   GETFROMHTML = sText

 onErrorExit:
   on error goto 0
End Function
```

Used in Calc cells like so:

```
=GETFROMHTML(E2; "<h3 class=""product-name""")
```

or

```
=GETFROMHTML(E2; "<span class=""price""")
```

Using a `Sub` could look like this:

```
sub getProductNameAndPrice()
   on error resume next

   oDoc = ThisComponent
   oSheet = oDoc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet

   for r = 0 to 9 'row 1 to 10 (0 based)

     sURL = oSheet.getCellByPosition(4, r).String 'get string value from column 4 (E)

     oSimpleFileAccess = createUNOService ("com.sun.star.ucb.SimpleFileAccess")
     oInpDataStream = createUNOService ("com.sun.star.io.TextInputStream")
     oInpDataStream.setInputStream(oSimpleFileAccess.openFileRead(sUrl))
     if not isNull(oInpDataStream.InputStream) then 
       dim delimiters() as long
       sContent = oInpDataStream.readString(delimiters(), false)

       sStartTag = "<h3 class=""product-name"""

       lStartPos = instr(1, sContent, sStartTag)
       if lStartPos <> 0 then
         lEndPos = instr(lStartPos, sContent, "</")
         lStartPos = lStartPos + 1 + len(sStartTag)
         sText = trim(replace(replace(mid(sContent, lStartPos, lEndPos-lStartPos), chr(10), ""), chr(13), ""))

         oSheet.getCellByPosition(5, r).String = sText
       end if 

       sStartTag = "<span class=""price"""

       lStartPos = instr(1, sContent, sStartTag)
       if lStartPos <> 0 then
         lEndPos = instr(lStartPos, sContent, "</")
         lStartPos = lStartPos + 1 + len(sStartTag)
         sText = trim(replace(replace(mid(sContent, lStartPos, lEndPos-lStartPos), chr(10), ""), chr(13), ""))

         oSheet.getCellByPosition(6, r).String = sText
       end if   

     end if

   next

   on error goto 0
end sub
```

This code takes the URLs from column `E` rows 1 to 10 and writes product name in column `F` and price in column `G` of the row.

Comment: A huge thank you!!!
While it works flawlessly with up to ten entries, fetching the product name and price of nearly 500 entries freezes the whole documents for minutes.
So is there a way to fetch the data in batches, like five at a time, have a small break and continue with another five?
When I save a document with your function, then opening also takes nearly 5 minutes, because Calc seems to fetch the data again. Can I somehow prevent that and fetch the data only on demand?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the way I implemented your script. I just added it to the macros [this](https://i.imgur.com/m1z0c3y.png) way. Is that the proper way to do it?

Comment: @DMT: Since this macro is used as user defined function in Calc, it will run every time the sheet is calculated. The performance is mainly dependent of your Internet connection performance. Maybe you could programming this as `Sub` instead of a `Function`. Then this `Sub` could be called manually (via Tools-Macros or via customized menu or via a button) if needed.

Comment: I've copied your updated macro (onErrorExit) and replaced Function with Sub, as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/TkWIdSr.png), but I'm getting an error message after launching it: `exit function` (line 15) should have a `sub`. After altering that, I receive `wrong number of parameters!`
Please bear with me, since I'm not familiar with macros at all. What would be the proper way to turn a function into a sub?

Comment: @DMT: Using a `Sub` is a totally different approach than using a `Function`. It is not only renaming the signature. Instead the whole approach has to be rethink. So if you are not familiar with macros for Libreoffice, you wil not be able solving this. You will need getting familiar with macros  for Libreoffice first.

Comment: @DMT: See my supplement.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness to help me with that `Sub`! I would lost without your help. May you have a fulfilling life!